# Expression <c:if> and {fn:length} in JSF JSTL

Tags: jsf, jstl

I can't enter in  even when it is true.

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(car.sela.seal) > 0}">

    <p:graphicImage value="/css/images/Sans.png" style="width:200px; height:200px" /> 

</c:if>
```

Comment: Just guessing, is the `#{car}` defined as `<p:dataTable var="car">` or so? By the way, see also the 2nd item currently in "Related" list on right column.

Comment: #{car} is define as <p:dataTable var="car">

Comment: And, for future questions, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. A lot of context was missing from the question. Your problem namely doesn't manifest when someone copypastes this code in its entirety into the `<h:body>` of a minimalistic templateless page in a fresh new project with most minimal configuration and most recent versions, and stubs the necessary variables for testing. Oh, your code is in its current form also implying that your problem disappears when you remove the `style` attribute ;)